what should be a naming for internal libraries cloned from public libraries
So lets assume we have a public library in version 2.3.1
We are currently using nugets in this version of library.
We are planning to clone it to our repository and apply changes only for our company - all this with authors agreement.
How should we version it? Should we start with 3.0.0?
We are planning to merge changes from public repo from time to time. It might also reach 3.0.0 at some point.
We are not planning to change library name or should we?
What I'm planning to do is to leave exact version which is currently in public library 2.3.1 and increase version depending on changes we will apply.
